# How to handle device allowIncomingWhileBusy property on Twilio

Tags: twilio

I'm using @twilio/voice-sdk and I would like to understand how Twilio handles the following scenario based on *allowIncomingWhileBusy* flag.

I have a case where:

- client_A calls client_B -> there is an outgoing call for person A,
- client_C calls client_A that is talking to client_B -> there is an incoming call for person A

When allowIncomingWhileBusy is false the `device.on('incoming', (conn) => { ... }` doesn't get triggered.

If I set allowIncomingWhileBusy flag to true I see that if goes into the device incoming handler, but the connection gets cancelled automatically.

```
device.on('incoming', (conn) => {
conn.on('cancel', () => {
      // it ends up here, but I don't want to cancel the incoming connection.
    })
```

Why in a second scenario the connection gets cancelled?

I would like to achieve a solution where if client_A has an incoming call during another one I'll open a popup that allows him to either decline the incoming call or end the current connection and accept the new one. Isn't allowIncomingWhileBusy made especially for cases like this one?

My device incoming handler looks like this:

```
  device.on('incoming', (conn) => {
      onIncomingCall({ conn }) // this only sets the calling widget state in a reducer

      conn.on('reject', () => { callEnded() }) 
      conn.on('disconnect', () => { callEnded() }) 
      conn.on('cancel', () => { callEnded() }) // callEnded sets the widget state in the reducer
      conn.on('error', (err) => { callError(err) })
    })
```

Comment: Are you doing anything else with the incoming calls? Can you share the rest of your code within the `device.on("incoming", (conn) => { })` function?

Comment: @philnash I included the snippet in a question

Comment: What does the state update to when you have an incoming call and an existing call? As far as I know, when you have `allowIncomingWhileBusy` set to true the second incoming call should not be immediately cancelled (why have the setting, otherwise?) so there may be something within your app that isn't handling that state correctly and cancelling the call. Do you see what I'm getting at?

Comment: @philnash
      `device.on('incoming', (conn) => { conn.on('cancel', () => {
          console.log('entered incoming: ', conn) }) })`

If I get rid of other things it acts the same
Is there another place I should be looking for potential errors on my side?

Comment: I was asking about the update to the state that you make. Can you share that?